# Formatting Figures in LaTeX

Tags: image, layout, label, latex

What I want is to give my graph a label of 'Figure 1.1'

```
 \begin{figure}
 \caption{}
 \includegraphics[width=5in,scale=0.5]{picture1.pdf}
 \end{figure}
```

However this produces 2 problems:

1) Before I just put

```
   \includegraphics[width=5in,scale=0.5]{picture1.pdf}
```

and that inserted the picture nicely into the middle of my page of text. But using the above procedure seems to force the picture to the top of my page. Is there someway I can disable this?

2) The labelling of the figure comes out as 'Figure 1.1:'. But I don't want the colon to be there. I simply want 'Figure 1.1'. Is there someway to supress the colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) of the `caption` package, you can change the formatting in multiple ways.

1. When loading the package, you may define global options as such. `\usepackage[options]{caption}`
2. After loading the package, for global options. `\captionsetup{options}`
3. When you want specific options, i.e. a single caption, use the `\captionsetup{options}` inside the `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`.

To change the separator to none, you want to use the `labelsep=none` option.